# Archiving Core Data entity with a relationship

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I want to be able to support copy and paste for a tableview row showing a core data entity. This entity has one attribute and two relationships. When I use the dictionary archiving technique recommended by Apple (from 'NSPersistentDocument Core Data Tutorial') I find that the relationships throw an error.  Here's the essential piece of code where the problem occurs:

```
for (id sectionObject in selectedSectionsArray){
    NSDictionary *thisDictionary = [sectionObject dictionaryRepresentation];   // 'sectionObject' has 1 attribute and 2 relationships (one-to-many)
    [copyObjectsArray addObject:[sectionObject dictionaryRepresentation]];
}
NSPasteboard *generalPasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[generalPasteboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:MSSectionsPBoardType, NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:self];
NSData *copyData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:copyObjectsArray];   // Here's where it crashes. ERROR MESSAGE: "-[NSManagedObject encodeWithCoder:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22fd410"
```

Therefore, it seems the only way to copy a relationship to the pasteboard must be to archive its  URI. In that case, I have to deal with the headache of referencing temporary ID's. Could someone please confirm that this is the case? Does it have to be so hard?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the "NSPersistentDocument Core Data Tutorial"? I found only the version for Mac OS X 10.4 which says "Not recommended" on the title page.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't read that document closely enough. In the section **Custom Employee Logic**, it explains that *relationships will not be copied* for several reasons described there. It then explains how the code handles copying only specific attributes. It seems like you followed the document as far as choosing specific attributes to copy but not about leaving out relationships.

As for the error you're seeing,

```
-[NSManagedObject encodeWithCoder:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x22fd410
```

This happens because you're calling `archivedDataWithRootObject:` on a dictionary that contains objects that don't conform to `NSCoding`, specifically, your managed objects. Archiving like this only works automatically for property list types-- for everything else, you have to implement `NSCoding`, or you get this error.

Copying a managed object ID's URI is probably reasonable if you want to copy the relationships. If you're having problems with temporary object IDs, do one of the following:

- Save changes
- Call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` for the objects to get permanent IDs without saving.